# Can I apply declarative rollup summary on affiliation object

Tags: dlrs

I have contact object that is associated with 'Affiliation' object which in turn is pointing to Account object.

Contact -> Affiliation -> Account

I have a 'priority' field on the affiliation record and the highest priority field on contact object. I want a declarative roll up summary that checks all the related affiliation records on the contact object, finds out the maximum priority out of all those records and populates it in 'Highest' priority field on contact object.Unfortunately when I put 'npe5__Affiliation__c' which is the API name for the affiliation object, in the declarative rollup summary, it does not detect the object and says that it does not exist. Can we not use Affiliation object in Declarative Rollup summary?

Thanks

Comment: The best resource for DLRS support is the [Success community group here](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F9300000009O5pCAE).

Comment: If I understand your description properly, it sounds as though you may be asking dlrs to do a roll-up on contact records and put the roll-up results on the same object (contact) the roll-up is derived from. That could be the source of your problem. Affiliation__c is a Junction Object and the best you should be able to do is a lookup to a field on it.